# The series $a_n$ converges and $a_n>0$. Check if the series $\frac{\sin a_n}{a_n}$ converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> I tried to prove that it does not converge by showing that the series $b_n=\frac{\sin a_n}{a_n}$ does not converge to $0$. But I am stuck with a limit of the kind $\frac{0}{0}$.

Thanks for helping me proceeding from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sum a_n$ converges, you have that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$. You should know (*) that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin a_n}{a_n} = 1$, hence $\sum \frac{\sin a_n}{a_n}$ is divergent.

(*) To prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$, write $\frac{\sin x}{x} = \frac{\sin x - \sin 0}{x-0}$ so that the limit becomes simply $\sin'(0) = \cos(0) = 1$.

Comment: How do you prove $\sin'(0)=\cos 0$?

Comment: @DavidMitra: it depends on how $\sin$ is defined in the first place. I'm sure that the author of the question proved this before studying series!

Comment: In that case, I'm sure he used the fact that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}{\sin x\over x} =1$ to establish the derivative formula.

Comment: @DavidMitra: well, maybe he did. Since he explicitly said "I am stuck with a limit of the kind $\frac{0}{0}$", I believe that it was the core of the question. I admit that I didn't know how to tackle this point without going too far beyond the scope of the question, and took for a known fact that cosine is the derivative of sine. If you feel like this answer is not appropriate, please mind posting a better answer, since the OP didn't accept mine yet!

Comment: Your answer is perfectly fine, and no doubt is the intended solution. I just have qualms with your proof in "(*)"; the reasoning there is at worst, circular.

Comment: Actually you are right, I should've know that lim sinx/x is 1. they told us it without proof but we can use it. Thanks